# Memcache vs Redis vs Javascript Hash object

Tags: javascript, caching, memory, redis, memcached

I know memcache and redis are used when caching needs to be there for more than one servers. 
I'm creating a node application which will run on single server only and uses mysql as db, and i need to hash around 100,000 keys and each key will contain json string of 200 in length, so that i dont have to call mysql for reads.

If i use memcache or redis i will use a callback to get my data, but if i use javascript hash i can get the data synchronously, but will it affect the application somehow, like high usage of memory. Which one i should be using for a application like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know memcache and redis are used when caching needs to be there for more than one servers.

Not necessarily, for instance Facebook puts a memcache instance in front of each of their mysql servers. You can use Redis/Memcache for fast computation (e.g. real-time analytics) without having a whole cluster.

> and i need to hash around 100,000 keys and each key will contain json string of 200 in length, so that i dont have to call mysql for reads.

It seems like premature optimization to mee, if MySQL have enough RAM (the dataset live in memory) you don't have to worry about performance, that's just 100 keys.

> If i use memcache or redis i will use a callback to get my data

If really depends on what language you use (Ruby and Python offers synchronous Redis clients) and what type of paradygm is used (event-loop, thread pool...)

> but if i use javascript hash i can get the data synchronously

To be more precise, that's just because you are using node_redis and not because you are using a javascript "hash" (an object in fact).

> but will it affect the application somehow, like high usage of memory

It depends if you are loading all keys in your process or not, if you are using a [**Redis Hash**](http://redis.io/commands#hash), you will be able to only query the field you want and not the whole field each time.

> Which one i should be using for a application like this?

The best thing to keep in mind is to lower the number of application you have to maintain in your stack while still using the right tool for the right job. Here MySQL could be enough but if you really want to use Redis or MemCached, I would go for Redis. It will offers simirarly the same features as memcached with the same performances will allowing you to use its other data-structures in the future without needing another application in your stack.

Moreover, if you put all your data in a Redis HASH, you will be able to retrieve a field (hget) or a group of fields (hmget) or all fields (hgetall) with just one call.

Finally, regarding [**recent statistics**](http://db-engines.com/en/ranking) and Redis ecosystem ([**GUI**](https://redsmin.com), [**hosting**](http://venturebeat.com/2013/11/04/garantia-data-becomes-redisdb-grabs-9m-as-it-passes-thousand-customer-mark/), [librairies](https://github.com/search?q=redis&ref=cmdform), ...), Redis seems to be way more future proof than Memcached if you really want to go that way.

**Disclaimer**: I am the founder of [**Redsmin**](https://redsmin.com), an online developer oriented service for administrating and monitoring Redis.

Answer (score 1):

It depends- you could even opt for memcached over mysql :). For simple operation such as only -readonly just storing it within your javascript code (I believe as dictionary objects) is enough. But be sure that you have enough RAM :) .

Comment: I'm using mysql for persistance and transactions. And redis provides transactions and persistance(not in default configuration). But what will be the result if redis,memcache or javascript dictionary holds 100,000 keys. which one would be better.

Comment: The native code would perform better but it depends upto you how to implement your dictionary object so that you can retrieve at O(1) .